# Display .png image on a web page

Tags: jquery, html

i want to display images in my page, But the problem i am facing is my web page displaying all .jpeg images but it is not displaying *.png images why is it??

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q="+q+"&json.wrf=?", function(result){
    var html="";
    // If no search results
    if(result.response.numFound==0)
    {
     html+= "<br>We're sorry, we found no results for <b>"+document.getElementById("queryString").value;
    }
    else
    {
      html+= "<br>Total Results Found <b> "+ result.response.numFound+"</b> for "+"<b>"+document.getElementById("queryString").value+"</b> keyword";
        // Parse solr response and display it on web page
            $.each(result.response.docs, function(i,item){
             var src1=item.image;
             // Check if there is a image  
                if(src1!= null && src1!= ""){

                      html+="<p><br>"+"<img src="+src1+ " />";
                  }
            // If not insert a default image  
                  else
                  {

                      src1="images/products/default.bmp";
                      html+="<p><br>"+"<img src="+src1+ " />";
                  }
                  html += "<br>UID_PK: ="+ item.UID_PK;
                  html += "<br>Name: ="+ item.name;
                 // html += "<br>Description: ="+ item.description;
                 html+="<br>Price:="+item.price
            });
    }

            $("#result").html(html);
```

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: What does Firebug say on each of those image requests? How about when you view those imaged individually by entering their direct address in the browser address bar?

Answer (score 2):

First try manually loading the images using the URL bar of your browser. If that works then there is a problem with your `<img>` tag or file path. Use Firebug or similar browser plugin to track it down.

If that doesn't work, and the file definitely exists, then it could be a MIME type issue with the server or file permissions. Check your server's error log for more information.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
 <img src="/path/to/my/image.png" alt="My Image" />
```

Comment: i am able to display .jpeg images in this way, the problem is it is not displaying .png images

Comment: @Romi it can't be the case you might have mistaken in path

Comment: i am getting json object and by parsing it am getting images path, this path contains images of type jpeg and png but i am able to display .jpeg but not .png. and i have checked my image folder contains both type of images

Answer (score 0):

Check the file access permissions on your PNGs.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation